# React cant read property of object from array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-router

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import HomeNavbar from './HomeNavbar.js'
import axios from 'axios';
import './AllBeers.css'

function SingleBeer(props) {

    let id = props.match.params._id
    const [beers, setBeers] = useState(['']);
    const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://ih-beers-api2.herokuapp.com/beers')
            .then(res => {
                setBeers(res.data);
            });
    },[]);

    setSelectedBeer(beers.find(x => x._id === id));

    return (
        <div>
            <HomeNavbar />
            <img id="beerPictures" src={selectedBeer.image_url} alt="A Beer Pic"></img>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.name}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.tagline}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.first_brewed}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.attenuation_level}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.description}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.contributed_by}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleBeer;
```

selectedBeer console.log's as an object, but it cannot access any of the properties, so none of the selectedBeer.name's and so on work. Anyone have an idea as to why?

Comment: where is the console and what are its results? can you share more details about your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should pass the initial value while using useState.
2. You mustn't use setSelectedBeer in the body of the function component.
   If not, it will called every update.

Try the following code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import HomeNavbar from './HomeNavbar.js'
import axios from 'axios';
import './AllBeers.css'

function SingleBeer(props) {

    let id = props.match.params._id
    const [beers, setBeers] = useState(['']);
    const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://ih-beers-api2.herokuapp.com/beers')
            .then(res => {
                setBeers(res.data);
                setSelectedBeer(res.data.find(x => x._id === id));
            });
    },[]);


    return (
        <div>
            <HomeNavbar />
            <img id="beerPictures" src={selectedBeer.image_url} alt="A Beer Pic"></img>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.name}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.tagline}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.first_brewed}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.attenuation_level}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.description}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.contributed_by}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleBeer;
```

Comment: It didn't cross my mind that i needed to have my selected beer definition in my axios to make sure it was able to reach beers array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`selectedBeer` is undefined on first render as per `const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState();`. So you will get an error on first render. Once you set it to an object, then those `selectedBeer.name ...` will work. You can quickly fix it by doing: `const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState({});`. That way you won't get that error on first render.

Also this `const [beers, setBeers] = useState(['']);` should be `const [beers, setBeers] = useState([]);` to make an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use useEffect for setSelectedBeer.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import HomeNavbar from './HomeNavbar.js'
import axios from 'axios';
import './AllBeers.css'

function SingleBeer(props) {

    let id = props.match.params._id
    const [beers, setBeers] = useState(['']);
    const [selectedBeer, setSelectedBeer] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://ih-beers-api2.herokuapp.com/beers')
            .then(res => {
                setBeers(res.data);
            });
    },[]);

    // Updated Code
    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedBeer(beers.find(x => x._id === id));
    },[beers]);

    return (
        <div>
            <HomeNavbar />
            <img id="beerPictures" src={selectedBeer.image_url} alt="A Beer Pic"></img>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.name}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.tagline}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.first_brewed}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.attenuation_level}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.description}</h3>
            <h3>{selectedBeer.contributed_by}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleBeer;
```